# Firebase RTD recursive security rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my Firebase Realtime Database, I have a comment and reply structure as shown below.

```
{
  "post-comments": {
    "$postId": {
      "pushKey1": {
        "uid": "uid1",
        "text": "comment 1",
        "replies": {
          "pushKey2": {
            "uid": "uid2",
            "text": "reply 1",
            "replies": {
               ... and so on
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All comments will be public to read. I would like to write a recursive security rule (since there can be any number of nested `"replies"` fields) that only lets a user:

- push if the new data has a matching `auth.uid` and `uid` field
- update a comment/reply if `auth.uid` matches the existing `uid` field
- deletion will be handled via soft-deletion, so it is essentially the same as an update

Is this possible? I did some googling, and this link came up as a search result: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior#recursive_wildcards, but that section of the page doesn't seem to exist anymore. Does this functionality still exist? Or is there another way to do this? If it matters, I'm using it client side with React.

Comment: That page of documentation refers to Firestore, which has a different rules system than Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common pattern to see hierarchies like this from developers new to Realtime Database, since it supports hierarchies it makes sense to want to use them.

But there is no way to define recursive security rules like that.

It is also fairly uncommon to see a recursive data model in a mature Firebase app, precisely because it makes access control hard.

I'd recommend storing the comments in a flat list, with a `parentId` in there. Give the top-level comments a `parentId` of `none` or whatever other fixed value, and you can query all you need.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you! (Thinking out loud here) I was initially worried about pagination being difficult in a flat structure, but I could easily construct a query to find the N most recent comments with `parentId == null`. From there, I can make another query to find replies using the `parentId` field, instead of loading the entire top N comment threads all at once.